# Can't play games fullscreen, Only see black but can hear them

Tags: games, fullscreen

I have installed several games from steam, but when I open all of them they go to full screen and the screen is black. I can hear the sounds of the game but can see nothing. My GPU is a AMD Radeon 6858 and I have Catalyst 13.4 on Elementary OS Luna beta 2. Any ideas as to how I can go about preventing this?

Comment: Have you checked to verify that the game runs at a resolution your hardware supports?

Comment: They all support a very wide range of resolutions as does my hardware. On a few games with steam I can make them run windowed and them set there resolutions to the same of that as my monitor, which is 1920x1080 then turn fullscreen on and they work, but most of my games can only change the resolution in game, which of course I can't do

Comment: That sounds *very* much like something doesn't like the particular resolution the game wants to run at by default. I don't know anything about Steam but maybe that can at least provide a hint as to where to start looking.

Comment: I belive it to be FGLRX, I never had an issue, other then the games running far to slow, prior to installing it. But no matter the resolution of the game, it can not be fullscreened unless its set to 1920x1080.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the Gala window management. At the moment there's not a particularly good solution (that I know of) other than temporarily relenquishing control of the windows to compiz (which Ubuntu uses).

When you want to game:

```
compiz --replace
```

When you're done:

```
gala --replace
```